# How to match Neo4j node or relationship count when filtering on node or relationship property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph:

```
CREATE (c1:Contract { id: "V-9087-4321" }),
       (c2:Contract { id: "V-8046-2304" }),
       (p:Partner {id: "C-4837-4536"}),
       (p)-[:POLICY_HOLER]->(c1),
       (p)-[:POLICY_HOLER]->(c2)

MATCH (p:Partner) WHERE p.id = "C-4837-4536"
CREATE (c:Claim { id: "ef70", date: "2019-04-27" }),
       (p)-[:CLAIMANT {on: "2019-04-27"}]->(c)

MATCH (p:Partner) WHERE p.id = "C-4837-4536"
CREATE (c:Claim { id: "ab90", date: "2019-04-28" }),
       (p)-[:CLAIMANT {on: "2019-04-28"}]->(c)
```

I want to find all partners who have more than one claim after April 1st:

I've tried this:

```
MATCH (claim:Claim)<-[r:CLAIMANT]-(p:Partner)
WITH count(r) as cnt, p, claim
WHERE cnt > 1 AND claim.date > '2019-04-01'
RETURN cnt, p.id
```

It doesn't work, because (if I remove the where clause), it is returning the two claims each with `cnt=1`, rather than actually aggregating them. I've tried selecting based on `claim.date` as well as `r.on`.

How can this be done with Cypher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@cybersam** explained about aggregate functions very well. I suggest looking at their answer to understand how aggregate functions work. But their query is not filtering claims based on the count.

**You can use the following query to find all partners who have more than one claim after April 1st:**

```
MATCH (claim:Claim)<-[r:CLAIMANT]-(p:Partner)
WHERE claim.date > '2019-04-01'
WITH count(r) as cnt, p 
WHERE cnt > 1
RETURN cnt, p.id
```

Answer (score 1):

The neo4j [aggregating functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/) (like `COUNT()`) use the non-aggregating terms in the same `WITH` or `RETURN` clause as the "grouping keys".

In your example's `WITH` clause, the grouping keys are `p` and `claim`, so the `COUNT()` function is counting the number of `r` relationships between each distinct `p` and `claim` pair (and so the count will always be 1). What you actually want instead is the number of `r` relationships for each `p`.

Assuming every `Partner` node has a unique `id`, you can find all partners who have more than one claim after April 1st using this simplified query:

```
MATCH (claim:Claim)<-[:CLAIMANT]-(p:Partner)
WHERE claim.date > '2019-04-01'
RETURN COUNT(claim) AS cnt, p.id
```

If you also want to return a list of all the claims for each matching partner:

```
MATCH (claim:Claim)<-[:CLAIMANT]-(p:Partner)
WHERE claim.date > '2019-04-01'
RETURN COUNT(claim) AS cnt, COLLECT(claim) AS claims, p.id
```

In addition, faster searches you should create either an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) or a [uniqueness constraint](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/current/cypher-intro/schema/#cypher-intro-schema-constraints) on `:Claim(date)`.

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't fulfill my requirements because it also returns partners with just one claim. I only want those with more than one.